# POST request on iOS necessary headers

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, post

I am sending a POST method from my iOS app. My code is working fine, but I just copy-pasted it.

```
NSString *post = @"key1=val1&key2=val2";
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.nowhere.com/sendFormHere.php"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

**My question is: Is it a must to set anything in the HTTP header field?**

If yes, what header fields are necessary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Which header fields are necessary will be determined by the server you are sending the request to. `NSURLSession` and friends will happily submit any headers you want, or no headers at all.

Answer (score -1):

> From NSMutableURLRequest Class Reference:
>
> If the length of your upload body data can be determined automatically (for example, if you provide the body content with an NSData object), then the value of Content-Length is set for you.

a simple POST request might look like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.nowhere.com/sendFormHere.php"];
NSData *postData = [@"key1=val1&key2=val2" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; //The default HTTP method is “GET”.
[request setHTTPBody:postData]; //query string is sent in the HTTPBody of a POST request
```

Comment: Thanks! So the content type is not necessary either? What is the default content type?

Comment: @BalázsVincze There seems to be no default content type. But if postData is set, there are two types available: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data